# iZotope - Nectar

Tags: izotope, plug-in, voice

Did anyone try iZotope [nectar](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/nectar/examples.html)?
Look like nice and easy all-in-one plug-in.
[image]
<sub>(source: [izotope.com](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/nectar/images/nectar_main-view_large.png))</sub>

Comment: i will try it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nectar is great. If you are in hurry, you don't need to add 2,3 or more effects, Nectar has it all. From Compressors, DeEsser, Saturation, EQ to Pitch Correction , Breath Control, Compressors, Doubler, Gate, Limiter, Delay, and Reverb.

I will definitely buy it.

Answer (score 0):

iZotopes plug-ins are awesome. I love Ozone - and their RX software is just slick. They truly are all in one plug-ins. But because of this, they truly are DSP hogs. Comparing a compression plug-in to opening Ozone and using its compression plug-in, I would rather use the single use plug-in if that is all I needed.

Friggin love iZotope - they put out good Mastering software.

And I like their harmonic exciter for bringing out areas of the spectrum or stereo imager for spreading a background.

Answer (score 0):

could be just me but i'm getting Waves Signature Series vibes from this, only the knobs are actually labeled as to what they do..